# Why is there a black bar on top of my iPhone/iPad app when I run it on the iPhone simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-simulator

Whenever I run my iPhone / iPad app in the iPhone simulator, a black bar appears along the top of the screen which I can't seem to get rid of. On the iPad simulator, however, it looks fine and works great. Also tapping one of the buttons seems to cause a white screen to appear instead of the view on the iPhone, while on the iPad it doesn't seem to be troublesome.

http://twitpic.com/1gutqp

http://twitpic.com/1gutjr

Answer (score 2):

That's the status bar. When you're running on the iPad, you only get the one on top of the screen, not on the top of the iPhone screen.